# Vagrant/PuPHPet mouting shared folders

Tags: vagrant, mount, puphpet

I'm trying to set up vagrant using puPHPet for local testing.

My process has been to simply start from a near clean puPHPet file and check things slowly, updating the configuration each time an element has been shown to be working. I'm having problems mounting shared folders.

The folder I want sharing is:

`C:\Users\{username}\Documents\wip`

Wip has multiple folders in it - these contain my actual web files for different sites. For example, two separate sites, with separate domains would be:

```
C:\Users\{username}\Documents\wip\foo
```

or

```
C:\Users\{username}\Documents\wip\bar
```

In order to even check the sharing, I simply attempted to mount the folder `wip`.

In puPHPet, I have navigated to: `Deploy Target/Locally`, and in the `Shared Folders` section, I selected:

- Folder source `C:\\Users\\{username}\\Documents\\wip`
- Folder target `/var/www`

Note the following yaml (I know some server types seem to have problems):

```
    provider:
        local:
            box: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64
            box_url: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64
            box_version: '0'
            chosen_virtualizer: virtualbox
```

However, on vagrant up the following happens:

It gets to:
`==> testserver: /var/www => C:/Users/{username}/Documents/wip`

Here it hangs for about a minute, then I get the error:

Failed to mount folders in Linux guest. This is usually because the "vboxsf" filesystem is not available. Please verify that the guest additions are properly installed in the guest and can work properly. The attempted command was:

```
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u www-data`,gid=`getent group www-data | cut -d: -f3`,dmode=775,fmode=774 vflsf_jhtv3ju147hz /var/www
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u www-data`,gid=`id -g www-data`,dmode=775,fmode=774 vflsf_jhtv3ju147hz /var/www
```

The error output from the last command was:

```
/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: No such device
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the [vagrant vaguest plugin](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest) and let it install the host's VirtualBox Guest Additions on the guest system